# Django calculate difference between rows in ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

What I'm trying to do is avoid a potentially expensive calculation that I do after retreiving a queryset, but doing it during the query, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

For example, if I have a model like:

```
class DailyUsers(model.Model):
  date = models.DateField()
  users = models.IntegerField()
```

And I do the following annotation:

```
queryset = models.DailyUsers.annotate(
  unique_users=Window(
    UnionAggCardinality(F("users")),
    order_by=F("date").asc(),
  )
).values("date", "unique_users")
>> [
     {"date": "2020-01-01", "users": 10}
     {"date": "2020-01-02", "users": 10}
     {"date": "2020-01-03", "users": 20}
     {"date": "2020-01-04", "users": 20}
     {"date": "2020-01-05", "users": 21}
   ]
```

I then need to perform the following calculation:

```
queryset = list(queryset)
result_list = [obj["result"] for obj in queryset]
for i in range(1, len(queryset)):
  queryset[i]["result"] = result_list[i] - result_list[i-1]
>> [ 
     {"date": "2020-01-01", "users": 10}
     {"date": "2020-01-02", "users": 0}
     {"date": "2020-01-03", "users": 10}
     {"date": "2020-01-04", "users": 0}
     {"date": "2020-01-05", "users": 11}
   ]
```

The calculation essentially subtracts the previous days users from the current day for the new value (skipping the first day).

Is there a way to do this in the orm? Ideally, I'd use a `Window` `Lag` function, but you can't nest Window functions.